# "View recent blog entries" only showing on admin's page but other users have blogs

Tags: nodes

"View recent blog entries" only showing on admin's page:

http://www.effectiveanimalactivism.org/user/1

But other users also have blogs:
user/5
and /user/10

that don't show up on their user pages.

Comment: Are you shure these Blog entries are published?

Comment: Yes, they are: http://www.effectiveanimalactivism.org/blog/5

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Answer: Permission to create new content.

Answer (score 0):

In the permissions page (under 'People' in Drupal 7), 'create new content' has to be checked for the users.