# View all Blog Entries page not functioning

Tags: users, nodes

I'm brand new to Drupal, and I'm working with an already existing installation.  I'm building a test website in Drupal on the side so that I can learn how everything works, but I'm having some issues with the live site (version 6.22) right now.

Specifically, there are links and pages to view all of a given user's Blog Entries.  (/blog/user_id)  This doesn't work for some users, though.  For some users, it will list all of their blog entries, but for others, the "content" area of the page is blank.

For testing purposes, I created a new article and changed its authorship several times; if the author was one who already had a working Blog Entries page it would appear, otherwise it would not.  The users all have the same role, and it doesn't appear to have anything to do with how long the user has been registered.  The only thing I can find in common is that for all the users that do not have working Blog Entries pages, they wrote their first Blog Entry within the last few months.

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39217/view-recent-blog-entries-only-showing-on-admins-page-but-other-users-have-blo) seems related, but this is working for some users with the role Blogger, and not for others.  Also, on the permissions page there is no "create new content" option, and "create blog entries" has been allowed for these users.

I can post any other information that may be needed.